# Free In-App purchase product (only for host some content at Apple)?

Tags: ios, download, in-app-purchase

The intention behind is to keep the initial app bundle size small, but provide some documents that can be downloaded later on for free.

Is there a way to do this with the Apple hosted content feature?

Answer (score 0):

I agree this would be a nice usage scenario, but it is not possible at the moment. You will have to host the content yourself. Amazon S3 provides a very stable and cheap solution for this scenario with low-to-zero maintenance cost.

Comment: Do they have some iOS SDK that handles all the interruprted downloads, with some easy-to-use interfaces? I have no wide experiences in backend issues.

Comment: Amazon S3 is a HTTP Server optimized for serving static files. You can use https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking which is a easy to use and very powerful library for interacting with HTTP (including stuff like pausing and resuming downloads: https://github.com/steipete/AFDownloadRequestOperation).